# Why is D3Dcompiler_43.dll Loaded and Unloaded every frame (huge performance hit), but it only happens when I have two windows of different sizes open?

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

**Why is D3Dcompiler_43.dll Loaded and Unloaded every frame?**

**Why does my two window direct-X 11 application drop from 2000 Hz to 12 Hz when I resize one of the windows?**

In simplified sample I have attached code from, it starts with two identical sized windows at 2000 Hz, but if I change the size of either one, the frame rate of both goes to 12 Hz.
If I minimize either one, I get back to full speed, 4000Hz with one window.

When it is running at 12 Hz, I get the following Output Trace EVERY FRAME:

**'Galaxies.exe' (Win32): Loaded  'C:\Windows\System32\D3Dcompiler_43.dll'**
**'Galaxies.exe' (Win32): Unloaded  'C:\Windows\System32\D3Dcompiler_43.dll'**

This trace comes out when I call IDGXISwapChain->Present().
This trace does not come out when running 2000Hz.

I do not expect to need D3Dcompiler_43.dll at all, since I build my shaders at compile time, not run time.  But if it did need it, then it should load it and keep it, not load each frame.

And if I make the window sizes match again, or minimize one, then the trace stops.

---

*C++, Directx 11*

My basic template is based on the Microsoft Sample "**SimpleTexturePC**".
Main changes from that template:

- compile textures into program rather than reading at run time
- compile shaders into program rather than reading at run time
- extend DeviceResources to be able to support more than one window
  by making arrays for all the resources, such as RenderTargetView
- Extending Main.cpp to create more than one window, and have a WinProc for each.
  Each of these unique WinProcs then calls a WinProcCommon with an "index" that identifies the window.
- Adding a second camera for use on 2nd window
- Adding a trace to the main application "Galaxies.cpp" so I could see the FPS.
  (the rest of the main application behavior is not in simplified sample).

Main.cpp

```
//
// Main.cpp
//

#include ...


namespace
{
    std::unique_ptr<Galaxies> g_game_p;
};

LPCWSTR g_szAppName0 = L"World1";
LPCWSTR g_szAppName1 = L"World2";
LPCWSTR g_szAppName2 = L"World3";


LRESULT CALLBACK WndProcWorld1(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProcWorld2(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProcWorld3(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProcCommon(UINT, HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);


// Entry point
int WINAPI wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, _In_ LPWSTR lpCmdLine, _In_ int nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    if (!XMVerifyCPUSupport())
        return 1;

    HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINITBASE_MULTITHREADED);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return 1;

    g_game_p = std::make_unique<Galaxies>();

    int border = getInvisableBorderWidth();

    // Register / create window 1  
    {
        // Register class
        WNDCLASSEXW wcex   = {};
        wcex.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEXW);
        wcex.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
        wcex.lpfnWndProc   = WndProcWorld1;
        wcex.hInstance     = hInstance;
        wcex.hIcon         = LoadIconW(hInstance, L"IDI_ICON1");
        wcex.hCursor       = LoadCursorW(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
        wcex.hbrBackground = reinterpret_cast<HBRUSH>(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
        wcex.lpszClassName = L"WindowClass1";
        wcex.hIconSm       = LoadIconW(wcex.hInstance, L"IDI_ICON1");

        if (!RegisterClassExW(&wcex)) // W implies unicode version.
            return 1;

        // Create window
        int w, h;
        g_game_p->GetDefaultWindowSize(w, h);

        
        HWND hwnd = CreateWindowExW(0, wcex.lpszClassName, g_szAppName0, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                    50 - border, 50, w, h, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr); 

        SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(g_game_p.get()));

        if (!hwnd)
            return 1;
        
        g_game_p->Initialize(kGameWindow1, hwnd, w, h);  // this chooses non-fullscreen location, though we will go full screen in a sec...

        ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    }

    // Register / create window 2
    {
        // Register class
        WNDCLASSEXW wcex   = {};
        wcex.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEXW);
        wcex.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
        wcex.lpfnWndProc   = WndProcWorld2;
        wcex.hInstance     = hInstance;
        wcex.hIcon         = LoadIconW(hInstance, L"IDI_ICON2");
        wcex.hCursor       = LoadCursorW(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
        wcex.hbrBackground = reinterpret_cast<HBRUSH>(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
        wcex.lpszClassName = L"WindowClass2";
        wcex.hIconSm = LoadIconW(wcex.hInstance, L"IDI_ICON2");

        if (!RegisterClassExW(&wcex)) // W implies unicode version.
            return 1;

        // Create window
        int w, h;
        g_game_p->GetDefaultWindowSize(w, h);

        HWND hwnd = CreateWindowExW(0, wcex.lpszClassName, g_szAppName1, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
            100 - border, 100, w + 00, h + 00, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

        SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(g_game_p.get()));

        if (!hwnd)
            return 1;

        g_game_p->Initialize(kGameWindow2, hwnd, w, h);

        ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    }


    // Main message loop 
    MSG msg = {};
    while (WM_QUIT != msg.message)
    {
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
        else
        {
            g_game_p->Tick();
        }
    }

    g_game_p.reset();

    CoUninitialize();

    return static_cast<int>(msg.wParam);
}


// First parameter "index" used to differentiate the three windows.
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProcCommon(UINT index, HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    WindowStruct& winInfo = g_deviceResources_p->GetWindowStruct(index);     

    auto galaxies_p = reinterpret_cast<Galaxies*>(GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA));

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_PAINT:
        if (winInfo.in_sizemove && galaxies_p)
        {
            RECT rc;
            GetWindowRect(hWnd, &rc);

            galaxies_p->OnWindowSizeChanged(index, rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top);

            galaxies_p->Tick();
        }
        else
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;

            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);    
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        break;

    case WM_MOVE:
        if (galaxies_p)
        {
            galaxies_p->OnWindowMoved(index);
        }
        break;

    case WM_SIZE:
        if (wParam == SIZE_MINIMIZED)
        {
            if (!winInfo.minimized)
            {
                winInfo.minimized = true;
                if (!winInfo.in_suspend && galaxies_p)
                    galaxies_p->OnSuspending();
                winInfo.in_suspend = true;
            }
        }
        else if (winInfo.minimized)
        {
            winInfo.minimized = false;
            if (winInfo.in_suspend && galaxies_p)
                galaxies_p->OnResuming();
            winInfo.in_suspend = false;
        }
        else if (!winInfo.in_sizemove && galaxies_p)
        {
            RECT rc;
            GetWindowRect(hWnd, &rc);

            galaxies_p->OnWindowSizeChanged(index, rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top);
        }

        break;

    case WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE:
        winInfo.in_sizemove = true;
        break;

    case WM_EXITSIZEMOVE:
        winInfo.in_sizemove = false;
        if (galaxies_p)
        {
            RECT rc;
            GetWindowRect(hWnd, &rc);

            galaxies_p->OnWindowSizeChanged(index, rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top);
        }
        break;

    case WM_GETMINMAXINFO:
        if (lParam)
        {
            auto info = reinterpret_cast<MINMAXINFO*>(lParam);
            info->ptMinTrackSize.x = 320;
            info->ptMinTrackSize.y = 200;
        }
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    case ... mouse cases
        Mouse::ProcessMessage(message, wParam, lParam);  
        break;                      

    case WM_KEYDOWN:
    case WM_KEYUP:
    case WM_SYSKEYUP:       
        Keyboard::ProcessMessage(message, wParam, lParam);  
        break;      

    case WM_MENUCHAR:
        return MAKELRESULT(0, MNC_CLOSE);
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);  
}


// Windows procedure x3
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProcWorld1(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
   return  WndProcCommon(kGameWindow1, hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}


LRESULT CALLBACK WndProcWorld2(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    return  WndProcCommon(kGameWindow2, hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}


LRESULT CALLBACK WndProcWorld3(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    return  WndProcCommon(kGameWindow3, hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}


// Exit helper
void ExitGame() noexcept
{
    PostQuitMessage(0);
}
```

Galaxies.cpp

```
//
// Galaxies.cpp
//

#include ...

// Global variables

std::unique_ptr<DX::StepTimer>           g_timer_p; 
std::unique_ptr<DX::DeviceResources>     g_deviceResources_p;

std::unique_ptr<DirectX::CommonStates>   g_states_p;
std::unique_ptr<padInput>                g_input_p;
std::unique_ptr<Camera>                  g_camera_p[2];
std::unique_ptr<HudText>                 g_text_p;


Galaxies::Galaxies() noexcept(false)
{
    g_deviceResources_p = std::make_unique<DX::DeviceResources>(DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM_SRGB);
    g_deviceResources_p->RegisterDeviceNotify(this);
}


void Galaxies::Initialize(UINT index, HWND window, int width, int height)
{
    static int once = true;
    if (once)
    {
        g_deviceResources_p->CreateDeviceResources();
        once = false;
    }

    switch (index)
    {
        case kGameWindow1:
        {
            g_timer_p     = std::make_unique<DX::StepTimer>();
            g_input_p     = std::make_unique<padInput>();
            g_camera_p[0] = std::make_unique<Camera>();
            g_camera_p[1] = std::make_unique<Camera>();
            g_text_p      = std::make_unique<HudText>();

            // PER OBJECT INITIALIZE
            g_camera_p[0]->Initialize(0);
            g_camera_p[1]->Initialize(1);
            g_input_p    ->Initialize();
            g_text_p     ->Initialize();


            g_deviceResources_p->SetWindow(index, window, width, height);
            g_deviceResources_p->CreateWindowSizeDependentResources(index);


            OnDeviceRestored();
            break;
        }
        case  kGameWindow2:
        case  kGameWindow3:
        default:
        {
            g_deviceResources_p->SetWindow(index, window, width, height);
            g_deviceResources_p->CreateWindowSizeDependentResources(index);
            break;
        }
    }
}



void Galaxies::GetDefaultWindowSize(int& width, int& height) const noexcept
{
    ...
}

void Galaxies::OnDeviceLost()
{
    g_states_p.reset();

    m_spPerFrameConstantBuffer.Reset();

    g_text_p->OnDeviceLost();
}


void Galaxies::OnDeviceRestored()
{
    CreateDeviceDependentResources();

    CreateWindowSizeDependentResources(0);      
    CreateWindowSizeDependentResources(1);

    WindowSizeChangeConfirmed(0);               
    WindowSizeChangeConfirmed(1);

    g_text_p->OnDeviceRestored();
}

void Galaxies::OnSuspending()
{
}

void Galaxies::OnResuming()
{
    g_timer_p->ResetElapsedTime();
}

void Galaxies::OnWindowMoved(UINT index)
{
    auto r = g_deviceResources_p->GetOutputSize(index);
             g_deviceResources_p->WindowSizeChanged(index, r.width, r.height);
}

// Pass in CURRENT (Last known) window size (icluding frame), so we can compare that with current size
// as read in deviceResources.
void Galaxies::OnWindowSizeChanged(UINT index, int width, int height)
{
    // returns false if size unchanged
    if (g_deviceResources_p->WindowSizeChanged(index, width, height))
    {
        CreateWindowSizeDependentResources(0);          

        WindowSizeChangeConfirmed(index);               
    }
}

                               
void Galaxies::Tick()
{
    UpdateRenderGPUTextures();  

    g_timer_p->Tick([&]()     
        {             
            UpdateInput();                 
            UpdateCameras();
            UpdateWorld(); 
        });

     RenderWorld(0);    

     if (!g_deviceResources_p->isWindowMinimized(1))
     {
         RenderWorld(1);
     }
}


void Galaxies::Clear(int index)
{
    // Clear the views.
    auto context          = g_deviceResources_p->GetD3DDeviceContext();
    auto renderTargetView = g_deviceResources_p->GetRenderTargetView(index);    
    auto depthStencilView = g_deviceResources_p->GetDepthStencilView(index);

    context->ClearRenderTargetView(renderTargetView, Colors::Black);

    context->ClearDepthStencilView(depthStencilView, D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH | D3D11_CLEAR_STENCIL, 1.0f, 0);
}


void Galaxies::CreateDeviceDependentResources()
{
    auto device = g_deviceResources_p->GetD3DDevice();
    g_states_p = std::make_unique<CommonStates>(device);   

    // Create constant buffers.  
    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bufferDesc = {};
    bufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
    bufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_CONSTANT_BUFFER;
    bufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
    bufferDesc.MiscFlags = 0;
    bufferDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(PerFrameConstantBuffer);

    DX::ThrowIfFailed(device->CreateBuffer(&bufferDesc, nullptr, m_spPerFrameConstantBuffer.ReleaseAndGetAddressOf()));
}

// Allocate all memory resources that change on a window SizeChanged event.
void Galaxies::CreateWindowSizeDependentResources(UINT index)
{
    // TODO: Initialize windows-size dependent objects here.
}



void Galaxies::UpdateRenderGPUTextures()
{
    // Don't try to render anything before the first Update.
    if (g_timer_p->GetFrameCount() == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
}


void Galaxies::UpdateInput()
{
    g_input_p->Update();

    if (g_input_p->isKeyDownEdge(escape))
    {
        ExitGame();
    }
}


void Galaxies::UpdateCameras()
{
    g_camera_p[0]->Update();                        
//  g_camera_p[1]->Update();
}


// Updates the world.
void Galaxies::UpdateWorld()
{
}

void Galaxies::RenderWorld(int index)       // index 0, 1.   not 2 (not edit window)
{
    if (g_timer_p->GetFrameCount() == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    Clear(index);


    // Update Constants Buffer with per-frame variables.
    // Though I now do this up to 3 times per frame - once per window.
    auto context   = g_deviceResources_p->GetD3DDeviceContext();
    auto d3dBuffer = m_spPerFrameConstantBuffer.Get();

    // Exclude 3rd window for now
    if (index != 2)
    { // PRE-LOCK
        MapGuard mappedResource(context, d3dBuffer, 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, 0);

        PerFrameConstantBuffer* data = reinterpret_cast<PerFrameConstantBuffer*>(mappedResource.get());

        g_camera_p[index]->GetPerFrameData(data);

        data->frameTime = g_timer_p->GetElapsedSeconds();
        if (g_input_p->isButtonToggleSet(leftShoulder))
        {
            data->frameTime *= 5;
        }
        data->totalTime = g_timer_p->GetTotalSeconds();

        int fps = (int)g_timer_p->GetFramesPerSecond();


        char buffer[TEXT_NUM_OF_CHAR];
        memset(buffer, 127, sizeof(buffer));


        if (index == 0)
        {
            snprintf(&buffer[0 * TEXT_NUM_CHAR_PER_ROW], TEXT_NUM_CHAR_PER_ROW + 1, "Window 1    ");
        }
        else
        {
            snprintf(&buffer[0 * TEXT_NUM_CHAR_PER_ROW], TEXT_NUM_CHAR_PER_ROW + 1, "Window 2     ");
        }
        snprintf(&buffer[TEXT_NUM_CHAR_PER_ROW], TEXT_NUM_CHAR_PER_ROW + 1, "Galaxies V0.01   ");
        snprintf(&buffer[2 * TEXT_NUM_CHAR_PER_ROW], TEXT_NUM_CHAR_PER_ROW + 1, "   FPS = %d              ", fps);
        

        for (int i = 0; i < TEXT_NUM_OF_CHAR; i++)
        {
            data->alpha[4 * i] = buffer[i] - 0x20;  // 0x20 is the first ascii char in our texture atlas.   It is " "
        }
    } // UNLOCK (in mappedResource destructor) 


    context->VSSetConstantBuffers(CONSTANTS_PER_FRAME, 1, &d3dBuffer);
    context->PSSetConstantBuffers(CONSTANTS_PER_FRAME, 1, &d3dBuffer);

    auto renderTargetView = g_deviceResources_p->GetRenderTargetView(index);
    auto depthStencilView = g_deviceResources_p->GetDepthStencilView(index);

    context->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &renderTargetView, depthStencilView);

    // Set the viewport.

    auto viewport = g_deviceResources_p->GetScreenViewport(index);
    context->RSSetViewports(1, &viewport);

    if (index != 2)
    {
        g_text_p->Render();
    }

    g_deviceResources_p->Present(index);                                            
}




void Galaxies::WindowSizeChangeConfirmed(UINT index)
{
    auto size = g_deviceResources_p->GetOutputSize(index);

    switch (index)
    {
    case (kGameWindow1):

        g_camera_p[0]->OnWindowSizeChanged(size.width, size.height);
        g_text_p     ->OnWindowSizeChanged(size.width, size.height);
        break;
    case (kGameWindow2):
        g_camera_p[1]->OnWindowSizeChanged(size.width, size.height);
        break;
    case (kGameWindow3):
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

DeviceResources.cpp

```
//
// DeviceResources.cpp 
//

#include ...

using namespace DirectX;
using namespace DX;

using Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr;


DeviceResources::DeviceResources(
    DXGI_FORMAT backBufferFormat,
    DXGI_FORMAT depthBufferFormat,
    UINT backBufferCount,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL minFeatureLevel,
    unsigned int flags) noexcept :
    
    m_backBufferFormat{ backBufferFormat },
    m_depthBufferFormat{ depthBufferFormat },
    m_backBufferCount{backBufferCount},
    m_d3dMinFeatureLevel(minFeatureLevel),

    m_window(),
    m_d3dFeatureLevel(D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_1),

    m_colorSpace(DXGI_COLOR_SPACE_RGB_FULL_G22_NONE_P709),  
    m_options(flags | c_FlipPresent | c_AllowTearing),      
        m_deviceNotify(nullptr)
{
    m_windowCount = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < c_MaxWindows; index++)
    {
        m_window[index] = nullptr;
        m_WindowStruct[index] = WindowStruct();
        m_screenViewport[index] = { 100, 100, 800, 600, 0, 1 };
    }      
}

void DeviceResources::CreateDeviceResources()
{
    UINT creationFlags = D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT;

    CreateFactory(); 

    ...

    // Determine feature levels
    ...


    ComPtr<IDXGIAdapter1> adapter;
    GetHardwareAdapter(adapter.GetAddressOf());

    // Create the Direct3D 11 API device / context.
    ComPtr<ID3D11Device> device;
    ComPtr<ID3D11DeviceContext> context;

    HRESULT hr = E_FAIL;
    if (adapter)
    {
      hr = D3D11CreateDevice(
        adapter.Get(),
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_UNKNOWN,
        nullptr,
        creationFlags,
        s_featureLevels,
        featLevelCount,
        D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
        device.GetAddressOf(),
        &m_d3dFeatureLevel,     
        context.GetAddressOf()  
        );
    }

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        // fall back to WARP device.
        ...
    }


    ThrowIfFailed(hr);

    ThrowIfFailed(device.As(&m_d3dDevice));
    ThrowIfFailed(context.As(&m_d3dContext));
}

// recreate every time the window size is changed.
void DeviceResources::CreateWindowSizeDependentResources(UINT index)
{
    if (!m_window[index])
    {
        throw std::exception("need valid window handle");
    }

    // Clear the previous window size specific context.
    ID3D11RenderTargetView* nullViews[] = { nullptr };
    m_d3dContext->OMSetRenderTargets(_countof(nullViews), nullViews, nullptr);
    m_d3dRenderTargetView[index].Reset();
    m_d3dDepthStencilView[index].Reset();
    m_renderTargetTexture[index].Reset();
    m_depthStencilTexture[index].Reset();
    m_d3dContext->Flush();

    // Determine the render target size in pixels.
    const UINT backBufferWidth  = std::max<UINT>(static_cast<UINT>(m_WindowStruct[index].currentPos.width), 1u);
    const UINT backBufferHeight = std::max<UINT>(static_cast<UINT>(m_WindowStruct[index].currentPos.height), 1u);
    const DXGI_FORMAT backBufferFormat = (m_options & (c_FlipPresent | c_AllowTearing | c_EnableHDR)) ? NoSRGB(m_backBufferFormat) : m_backBufferFormat;

    if (m_swapChain[index])
    {
        // If the swap chain already exists, resize it.
        HRESULT hr = m_swapChain[index]->ResizeBuffers(
            m_backBufferCount,
            backBufferWidth,
            backBufferHeight,
            backBufferFormat,
            (m_options & c_AllowTearing) ? DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_ALLOW_TEARING : 0u
            );

        if (hr == DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_REMOVED || hr == DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_RESET)
        {
            ...
        }
        else
        {
            ThrowIfFailed(hr);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Create a descriptor for the swap chain.
        DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC1 swapChainDesc = {};
        swapChainDesc.Width = backBufferWidth;
        swapChainDesc.Height = backBufferHeight;
        swapChainDesc.Format = backBufferFormat;
        swapChainDesc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
        swapChainDesc.BufferCount = m_backBufferCount;
        swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
        swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
        swapChainDesc.Scaling = DXGI_SCALING_STRETCH;
        swapChainDesc.SwapEffect = (m_options & (c_FlipPresent | c_AllowTearing | c_EnableHDR)) ? DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_DISCARD : DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD;
        swapChainDesc.AlphaMode = DXGI_ALPHA_MODE_IGNORE;
        swapChainDesc.Flags = (m_options & c_AllowTearing) ? DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_ALLOW_TEARING : 0u;

        DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FULLSCREEN_DESC fsSwapChainDesc = {};
        fsSwapChainDesc.Windowed = TRUE;

        // Create a SwapChain 
        ThrowIfFailed(m_dxgiFactory->CreateSwapChainForHwnd(
            m_d3dDevice.Get(),
            m_window[index],
            &swapChainDesc,
            &fsSwapChainDesc,
            nullptr, m_swapChain[index].ReleaseAndGetAddressOf()
            ));

        ThrowIfFailed(m_dxgiFactory->MakeWindowAssociation(m_window[index], DXGI_MWA_NO_ALT_ENTER));
    }


    // Create a render target view of the swap chain back buffer.
    ThrowIfFailed(m_swapChain[index]->GetBuffer(0, IID_PPV_ARGS(m_renderTargetTexture[index].ReleaseAndGetAddressOf())));

    CD3D11_RENDER_TARGET_VIEW_DESC renderTargetViewDesc(D3D11_RTV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D, m_backBufferFormat);
    ThrowIfFailed(m_d3dDevice->CreateRenderTargetView(
        m_renderTargetTexture[index].Get(),
        &renderTargetViewDesc,
        m_d3dRenderTargetView[index].ReleaseAndGetAddressOf()
        ));

    if (m_depthBufferFormat != DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN)
    {
        // Create a depth stencil view for use with 3D rendering if needed.
        CD3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC depthStencilDesc(
            m_depthBufferFormat,
            backBufferWidth,
            backBufferHeight,
            1, 
            1, 
            D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL
            );

        ThrowIfFailed(m_d3dDevice->CreateTexture2D(
            &depthStencilDesc,
            nullptr,
            m_depthStencilTexture[index].ReleaseAndGetAddressOf()
            ));

        CD3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC depthStencilViewDesc(D3D11_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D);
        ThrowIfFailed(m_d3dDevice->CreateDepthStencilView(
            m_depthStencilTexture[index].Get(),
            &depthStencilViewDesc,
            m_d3dDepthStencilView[index].ReleaseAndGetAddressOf()
            ));
    }

    // Set the 3D rendering viewport 
    m_screenViewport[index] = CD3D11_VIEWPORT(
        0.0f,
        0.0f,
        static_cast<float>(backBufferWidth),
        static_cast<float>(backBufferHeight)
        );
}


void DeviceResources::SetWindow(UINT index, HWND window, int width, int height) noexcept
{
    m_window[index] = window;

    int indent = 50 * (index + 1);

    RECTxywh windowPos = { indent - getInvisableBorderWidth(), indent, width, height };
    m_WindowStruct[index].setWindowedByWindowPos(windowPos, 0, true);
}


bool DeviceResources::WindowSizeChanged(UINT index, int width, int height)   
{
    RECTxywh newRc = { 0, 0, width, height };
    RECTxywh oldRc = { 0, 0, m_WindowStruct[index].currentPos.width, m_WindowStruct[index].currentPos.height };

    if (newRc == oldRc)
    {
        // i.e. size didnt actually change
        return false;
    }

    m_WindowStruct[index].setWindowedByWindowPos(newRc, 0, false);      
                                                                      
    CreateWindowSizeDependentResources(index);
    return true;
}

// Recreate all device resources
void DeviceResources::HandleDeviceLost(UINT index)
{
    if (m_deviceNotify)
    {
        m_deviceNotify->OnDeviceLost();
    }

    m_d3dDepthStencilView[index].Reset();
    m_d3dRenderTargetView[index].Reset();
    m_renderTargetTexture[index].Reset();
    m_depthStencilTexture[index].Reset();
    m_swapChain[index].Reset();
    m_d3dContext.Reset();
    m_d3dDevice.Reset();
    m_dxgiFactory.Reset();

    CreateDeviceResources();
    CreateWindowSizeDependentResources(index);

    if (m_deviceNotify)
    {
        m_deviceNotify->OnDeviceRestored();
    }
}


int  DeviceResources::getNumberOfMonitors()
{
    ComPtr<IDXGIAdapter1> adapter;
    GetHardwareAdapter(adapter.GetAddressOf());

    IDXGIOutput* output = NULL;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; DXGI_ERROR_NOT_FOUND != adapter->EnumOutputs(i, &output); ++i)
    {
        count++;        
    }

    return count;
}

RECTxywh DeviceResources::getMonitorSize(int monitor)
{
    RECT position = getMonitorPos(monitor);

    RECTxywh size(0, 0, position.right - position.left, position.bottom - position.top);

    return size;
}

// 1 based index into monitors
RECT  DeviceResources::getMonitorPos(int monitor)
{
    ComPtr<IDXGIAdapter1> adapter;
    GetHardwareAdapter(adapter.GetAddressOf());

    RECT pos = {};

    IDXGIOutput* output = NULL;
    int count = -1;
    if ( DXGI_ERROR_NOT_FOUND != adapter->EnumOutputs(monitor, &output) )
    {
        DXGI_OUTPUT_DESC outputDesc;
        HRESULT hr = output->GetDesc(&outputDesc);

        pos = outputDesc.DesktopCoordinates;
    }

    return pos;
}

RECT  DeviceResources::getWindowPos(int index)
{
    RECT windowRect;
    HWND window = m_window[index];
    GetWindowRect(window, &windowRect);

    return windowRect;
}

void  DeviceResources::setWindowPosition(int index, RECTxywh pos)
{
    HWND hWnd = m_window[index];
    SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_TOP, pos.left, pos.top, pos.width, pos.height, SWP_FRAMECHANGED)

    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL)
}

bool DeviceResources::isWindowMinimized(int index)
{
    return IsIconic(m_window[index]);
}


// Present the contents of the swap chain to the screen.
void DeviceResources::Present(int index)
{
    HRESULT hr = E_FAIL;
    if (m_options & c_AllowTearing)
    {
        hr = m_swapChain[index]->Present(0, DXGI_PRESENT_ALLOW_TEARING);

        Print(L"TRACE: Present Present %i \n", index);
    }
    else
    {
        hr = m_swapChain[index]->Present(1, 0);
    }


    m_d3dContext->DiscardView(m_d3dRenderTargetView[index].Get());

    if (m_d3dDepthStencilView[index])
    {
        // Discard the contents of the depth stencil.
        m_d3dContext->DiscardView(m_d3dDepthStencilView[index].Get());
    }

    if (hr == DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_REMOVED || hr == DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_RESET)
    {
        HandleDeviceLost(index);
    }
    else
    {
        ThrowIfFailed(hr);

        if (!m_dxgiFactory->IsCurrent())
        {
            CreateFactory();
        }
    }
}

void DeviceResources::CreateFactory()
{
    ThrowIfFailed(CreateDXGIFactory1(IID_PPV_ARGS(m_dxgiFactory.ReleaseAndGetAddressOf())));
}

void DeviceResources::GetHardwareAdapter(IDXGIAdapter1** ppAdapter)
{
...
}
```

Comment: Instead of pasting dozens of lines of C++ that we won't paste ourselves because it's tedious, why don't you post the full reproducing project somewhere on the web (github, etc.).https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Where in all this code are you actually calling the legacy DirectX SDK version of the D3DCompile API? Or perhaps, it's not you and its some "value-add" graphics tool?

Comment: All of my own shaders are compiled into bytecode in .h files at compile time. 
My own code never calls D3DCompile. 

I have several packages loaded  (directxmath, directxtex, directxtk) 
but no calls against those that should use or trigger the compile of any shader.

If I reduce my code to draw nothing, just clear buffers and present, the FPS is still bad if window sizes don't match....

Comment: The key point has to be that with this reduced setup I successfully render at more than 1000Hz for 9 seconds.
Only after that does the frame rate crash to 12Hz.
Only after that does it print the trace about loading / unloading the D3DCompiler.

This must be some kind of resource depletion or fragmentation. 
Then as memory is depleted, perhaps the D3DCompiler is unloaded, then sadly reloaded next frame.
But swap chain uses same memory over and over in alternating frames, right?
I'm not even writing any constants buffer in this reduced setup.
so what could be depleting GPU memory?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).